# Compilation Error in C-File handling

Tags: c, error-handling, compiler-errors

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
FILE *fp;
int main()
{
  int val;
  char line[80];
  fp=fopen("\Users\P\Desktop\Java\a.txt","rt");
  while( fgets(line,80,fp)!=NULL )
   {
     sscanf(line,"%d",&val);
     printf("val is:: %d",val);
   }
   fclose(fp);
   return 0;
}
```

Why is there a compile error in the line fp=fopen("\Users\P\Desktop\Java\a.txt","rt")?

Comment: What is the compile error? Try escaping the backslashes?

Answer (score 6):

Escape your backslashes.

```
fp=fopen("\\Users\\P\\Desktop\\Java\\a.txt","rt");
```

Answer (score 4):

```
xx.c:8:12: error: \u used with no following hex digits
  fp=fopen("\Users\P\Desktop\Java\a.txt","rt");
           ^
xx.c:8:12: warning: unknown escape sequence '\P'
xx.c:8:12: warning: unknown escape sequence '\D'
xx.c:8:12: warning: unknown escape sequence '\J'
```

The issue with the backslash. Backslash is an escape in a C char string.

Try this

```
  fp=fopen("\\Users\\P\Desktop\\Java\\a.txt","rt");
```

or this depending on your OS:

```
  fp=fopen("/Users/P/Desktop/Java/a.txt","rt");
```

Answer (score 2):

You may be familiar with how `"\n"` (newline) and `"\t"` (tab) are used in C-strings.

The compiler will look at any `\<Character>` and try to interpret it as an [Escape-Sequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx).

So, where you wrote `"\Users\P\Desktop\Java\a.txt"`, the compiler is trying to treat 
`\U`, `\P`, `\D`, `\J` and `\a` as special escape-sequences.
(The only one that seems to be valid is `\a`, which is the Bell/Beep sequence.  The others should all generate errors)

As others have said, use `\\` to insert a literal Backslash character, and *not* start an escape sequence.

**P.S.** Shame on you for not including the the compiler message in your question.
The worst questions all say, "I got an error", without ever describing what the error was.